# wix msi package fails to update driver, log shows DIFXAPP error

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installation

I'm trying to modify the Dokany project's wix msi installer to perform upgrades. It's close, but after a supposedly successful upgrade, the driver/service is not running like it is after standalone installation. It works fine if I uninstall the old version and install the new one separately, but updating, which does essentially the same thing, fails. Comparing the logs line by line shows this in the failing upgrade case:

`DIFXAPP: ERROR:  Unable to start service 'dokan1' because of error 0x422`

I assume this matches `ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED
1058 (0x422)
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it`

I was able to hack around this by adding this to the InstallExecuteSequence:
`<ForceReboot After="RemoveExistingProducts">UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</ForceReboot>`
but why does the install say it succeeded when the service couldn't be started?

Log here:
https://gist.github.com/zanderz/e9882870a4b3ff4d0ba143ff724d7c56#file-dokan-log-L667

The per machine package file can be seen here:
https://github.com/keybase/dokany/blob/zanderz/test_2016.08.02/dokan_wix/Dokan_x64.wxs